# How to delete script injected on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My wordpress site has this scripts all over the place.

Do anyone know how to fix this thing?

The scripts have this link:
`www.learningtoolkit.club`
`learningtoolkit.club`
`examhome.net`

Searched the files and found a dozen places with malicious code, but it's still on the site. I searched the data beaze too and it's OK.

Comment: You are not the only one.. https://www.computerbase.de/forum/threads/was-ist-hotopponents-site-site-js.1826682/

Comment: It is quite possible that your wordpress installation is compromised. You should consult your hosting provider.

Comment: You need to clean the site. It seems your site has been infected with a Malware.

Comment: Are you using any nulled themes or plugins?

Comment: I have removed all the redundant plugins and installed the latest updates.
Even if you turn off the plugin, the templates will still load the scripts.